How to make my Electron application serve a website
I am trying to build a "Stream Deck" like application, basicaly it should be a .exe built from electron that has an express api, a renderer to configure the application and a website that should be accessible from my local network to make requests to the api.
The problem I am encountering is that I'm trying to host the website using my electron application, is there anyway to do it?
I am using electron-vite with only the main and renderer processes and tried to include another Vite application to be bundled with them in a "client" folder.

Are you wanting to serve the exact same Electron HTML+JS through the web-server?

Two different applications, one will be for the app itself and another to be accessible in the local network
